# mongodb in podman with secret password

Tags: mongodb, podman

How can I pass a secret root password to mongodb when running in podman?

```bash
podman secret create mongodb-pw PASSWORDFILE
podman run -d \
    -e MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root \
    --secret=mongodb-pw,type=env,target=MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD \
    docker.io/mongodb/mongodb-community-server
```

fails with the error message

> Could not create admin user during database initialization.
> Take a look at your mongod configuration to see if something is wrong.

The environment variable is set however:

```bash
podman run -d \
    -e MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root \
    --secret=mongodb-pw,type=env,target=MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD \
    docker.io/mongodb/mongodb-community-server \
    sh -c 'echo $MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD'
# output: super-secret-password
```

Running the same command with the root password given on the command line works as expected (i.e., login with the specified password is possible).

```bash
podman run -d \
    -e MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root \
    -e MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=super-secret-password \
    docker.io/mongodb/mongodb-community-server
```

Comment: Have a look at PASSWORDFILE: `xxd PASSWORDFILE` - is there a line break? This may cause problems.

Comment: I assume you mean a line break at the end of the file?  With podman this makes no difference as any newlines are removed.  You can try this with `echo -e '123\n\nasdf\n\n' > PASSWORDFILE`

Comment: Well, when I tried your commands it didn't work. It was due to Windows line breaks ("\r\n"), because after removing it, MongoDB started. Great if Linux line breaks don't confuse Podman. Which version of Podman and Mongodb are you using?